# Does a language stay regular if you re-encode the input?

Tags: regular-languages

$\tau$ be a transformation that, applied to a word of $\Sigma_a^\star$, replaces each character with a word from a possibly different $\Sigma_b^\star$ and concatenates the resulting words. For instance, given a $\tau$ with the following translation table:

```
A -> AA
B -> AB
C -> BA
D -> BB
```

$\tau(ABC)=AAABBA$ and $\tau(DACB)=BBAABAAB$. Note that the words may not all have the same length. A translation table such as

```
A -> FOO
B -> BAR
C -> BAZ
D -> QUUX
```

is also valid.

Now, is $\{w'|w\in L\land w'=\tau(w)\}$ regular iff $L$ is a regular language as well?

Comment: What did you try?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @David I don't have the slightes clue how to prove this. Not homework.

Comment: This question is better than the one its a duplicate of, but that one already has good answers.

Comment: @Raphael I've nominated this for reopening as the duplicate has been deleted.

Comment: @Raphael Perhaps we should move the answers from the deleted questions here? Or at least undelete that question?

Comment: Wow, what a mess: late closure which let to a late deletion (as rejected migration), which then leaves the reference here dangling. Given there are more answers over there, I'm undeleting that one. If everybody moves their answers here, we can re-delete; the question isn't that great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes. This is generally called homomorphism, and regular languages are closed under homomorphism. Moreover, regular languages are closed under inverse homomorphism also. More precisely,
if $\tau$ is a homomorphism from alphabet $\Sigma$ to alphabet $\Delta$ and $L$ is a regular language over $\Delta$, then $\tau^{-1}(L)$ is also a regular language.

You can take a look [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12017/proof-that-the-regular-languages-are-closed-under-string-homomorphism) for more details, or the best is to take a look at this [book](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/ialc.html), which contains proofs about basic properties of regular languages.

Comment: The proof in the link you gave me seemingly only covers one direction (namely, that if $L$ is regular, so is $\tau(L)$). What about the other direction (if $\tau(L)$ is regular, then $L$ is regular)?

Comment: I updated my answer.